# Create user's account in postfix's server

Tags: 12.04, server, postfix

I have istalled postfix in ubuntu 12.04, so that a user can write and read its messages, that's for an user that I already create its account in the server. But what about a new user,I mean how could he create its own account ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your options are to either create a standard system user account for each user that you want to receive mail, or use Postfix's virtual mailboxes capabilities. You can find more about virtual mailboxes and virtual domains in the [Postfix documentation here](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html#virtual_mailbox).